# Qt 5 file not downloading from the web

Tags: qt

I'm trying to download a text file from the web for my GUI app to use. I first used an event loop, but the file would download a 0 byte file on the first attempt, but would be successful on subsequent attempts (the app uses a button to download). I then tried using a class member defined slot without the event loop, but the slot never gets called.

Here's the procedure with the event loop:

```
    void class1::downloadFile(const QString &url, const QString &aPathInClient)
    {

        QNetworkAccessManager m_NetworkMngr;
        QNetworkReply *reply= m_NetworkMngr.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
        QEventLoop loop;
        QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),&loop, SLOT(quit()));
        loop.exec();

        QUrl aUrl(url);
        QFileInfo fileInfo=aUrl.path();

        QFile file(aPathInClient+"/"+fileInfo.fileName());
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        file.write(reply->readAll());
        file.close();

        reply->deleteLater();

    }
```

Here's the procedure using the class member defined slot:

class1.h

```
    class class1: public QObject
    {


        Q_OBJECT

        public slots:

            void onRequestCompleted();

        public:

            QString df_url;
            QString df_path;

        public:

            void downloadFile(const QString &url, const QString &aPathInClient);

    };
```

class1.cpp

```
    void class1::downloadFile(const QString &url, const QString &aPathInClient)
    {

        df_url = url;
        df_path = aPathInClient;

        QNetworkAccessManager m_NetworkMngr;
        QNetworkReply *reply = m_NetworkMngr.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
        QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onRequestCompleted()));

        reply->deleteLater();
    }

    void class1::onRequestCompleted( ) 
    {

        QString url2;
        QString aPathInClient2;

        url2 = df_url;
        aPathInClient2 = df_path;

        QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());

        QUrl aUrl(url2);
        QFileInfo fileInfo=aUrl.path();

        QFile file(aPathInClient2+"/"+fileInfo.fileName());
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        file.write(reply->readAll());
        file.close();
        reply->deleteLater();

    }
```

Forgive the redundancy of variables. I'm just trying to get it to work at his point. I will clean that up later. Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any replies.

Edit:

I finally found the problem. I downloaded from another web site and everything is working now. Must have been a problem with the transfer from that first site. I am using the class member slot approach, abandoning the event loop approach.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
  //class1.h

    class class1: public QObject
    {

        //There's a lot more to the class, but here are the pertinent parts

        Q_OBJECT

        public slots:

            void onRequestCompleted();

        public:

            QString df_url;
            QString df_path;
            QNetworkAccessManager *m_NetworkMngr;
            QNetworkReply *reply;

        public:

            void downloadFile(const QString &url, const QString &aPathInClient);


    };

 //class1.cpp

    void class1::downloadFile(const QString &url, const QString &aPathInClient)
    {

        df_url = url;    //class variable
        df_path = aPathInClient;   //class variable


        m_NetworkMngr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); //class variable

        reply= m_NetworkMngr->get(QNetworkRequest(url)); //class variable

        QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onRequestCompleted()));


    }


    void class1::onRequestCompleted() {

        QString url2;
        QString aPathInClient2;

        url2 = df_url;
        aPathInClient2 = df_path;


        QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());


        QUrl aUrl(url2);
        QFileInfo fileInfo=aUrl.path();

        QFile file(aPathInClient2+"/"+fileInfo.fileName());
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        file.write(reply->readAll());
        file.close();


    }
```

The downloadFile procedure parameters:

url -string url of file I'm downloading

aPathInClient - string location of the folder that contains the file I'm updating

downloadFile gets called by a procedure that gets called by pressing a button. The entire class gets instanced with the button and then gets destroyed when the slot for the button completes. So the reply and network manager objects get destroyed when that happens.

Comment: "I then tried using a class member defined slot without the event loop, but the slot never gets called." - That's because you create the network manager on the stack, so it's deleted immediately at the end of downloadFile(). Make the networkmanager a class variable instead.

Comment: I made the network manager a class variable, and now now it downloads, but not on the first attempt, only on subsequent attempts. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm still using the member defined slot. Should I try the event loop with the change, or stick with the member defined slot. Note: the event loop approach works in Windows 7, just not my Linux virtual machine.

Comment: Note: the loop approach is not working in Windows 7.

Comment: About half the time it will download on the first attempt in Windows 7 using the event loop.

Comment: Slot! local event loops are evil. Check reply->errorString() in case it fails.

Comment: I finally found the problem. I downloaded from another web site and everything is working now. Must have been a problem with the transfer from that first site. I am using the class member slot approach, abandoning the event loop approach.

Comment: This is not a forum. If you have solved your own problem, you should answer your own question and accept it instead of updating your question with the solution.

Comment: And whoever down-voted the question should reconsider. The question was verbose and code was posted which shows forethought and effort before posting the question.

Comment: I didn't know I could answer my own question. The tips at the bottom says to edit the original post. I tried to do the best to provide the solution. Sorry if it wasn't done correctly. Thanks you guys for the replies and suggestions. It is much appreciated.